# Facebook login button not closing after login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to create a facebook login authenatication, however i keep having issues with when the user clicks the button it opens up the browser and i log in, however when i log in and give permission nothing happens and it does not close the browser and go back to the app. The other thing is when i open the app again and check the token it return nil even though it should be logged in already?

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        // Process error
    }
    else if result.isCancelled {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
        // should check if specific permissions missing
        if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile") && result.grantedPermissions.contains("user_friends")
        {

        }
    }

}
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
   //Check for access
    if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil) {
        print("Logged in")
    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToIntro", sender: self)
    }
```

**appDelegate**

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {


    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

**Plist**

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb1645871657973243</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>1645871657973243</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>testy</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Have you added the AppDelegate methods for FB integration? FB uses URL Schemes to communicate between browser and app which is why you need the app delegate methods

Comment: You also have to register FB schemes in your App's plist to make it work

Comment: i already did install plist

Comment: i've added my appdelegate

Comment: Yes I have noticed. Your methods are hooked and as you say you have configured your plist correctly as well. Maybe just to be sure, post the code of your plist here so that community can see if something is missing? Of course don't forget to hide your app sensitive data prior to posting it

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens and it does not close the browser and go back to the app" Normally with the new FBSDKLogin() when you press on the button a Safari WebKitView is opened and once you are logged in you can press "Done". Do you get to this screen at all?

Comment: I had a similar issue when my phone was on iOS 10 beta. With a phone on iOS 9 I did not have this issue.

Comment: i'm using ios 10 and xcode beta and swift 3. could this be the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented the FBSDK with iOS 10 and Swift 3 a few days ago and it wasn't very smooth. The big issue for me was probably what's happening to you - the new SDK wants to open the facebook app on the iPhone but the Simulator naturally doesn't have it. The check for this is simple - the following error:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I had this problem for a few days until I looked around and figured it out with the Apple dev forum. Another possible reason is that you haven't implemented the AppDelegate functions properly. The old FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(...) function is deprecated. After some searching I came up with the following implementation, which works for me:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [String : AnyObject] = [:]) -> Bool {
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as! String,
                                                          annotation: nil)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewDidLoad` method you have to put:

```
 yourLoginFacebookButton.delegate = self
```

In your Login class you have to put this implementation:

```
FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
```